# Display Null from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to display every thing in database to asp.net. But some of my value are null and some not. When I load to the page that null it will cause error. May I know how can I fix this problem? My mean is to display everything from database doesn't care it is NULL or having content.

```
SELECT m.PersonID, m.Picture,m.PersonName, t.title, t.Fileupload, t.contentBody,      t.dateInserted FROM person m, thread t  WHERE m.PersonID = t.PersonID AND t.threadID = @TID
```

The t.FileUpload in my database some of row are null and some contain contain. And the error is

```
system.invalidcastexception unable to cast object of type 'system.dbnull' to type 'system.string'
```

Comment: Code please, and exception details.

Comment: Please post some of the code to understand better.

Comment: Are you binding detail with some data control of asp.net?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Standard SQL coalesce function.

```
SELECT a.PersonID, 
Coalesce (a.Picture, othercolumn, anothercolumn, 'if all are null') as Picture
from tableA a
```

it will return the first not null value.

[Coalesce in mySQL](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)

or just simply:

```
Coalesce (a.Picture, '') as Picture
```

This will prevent invalidcastexception

Comment: but then now having another problem  System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Could not find specific column......

Comment: use alias: Coalesce (a.Picture, '') as Picture

Comment: No probs, enjoy it ;)

Comment: Accept the answers in your questions, if you are satisfied with them please.